# Getting an error when using 'souce [file]' in Navicat command line mode

Tags: mysql, powershell, navicat

I have a file named 'test.txt' that contains some SQL statements.
When I use PowerShell (Windows 8.1) and login MySQL, then use:

```
source d:/test.txt;
```

everything works out fine.

But when I use the same command in Navicat's (v11.0.10) command mode (press <kbd>F6</kbd> in Navicat) I got an error like:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source d:/test.txt;' at line 1

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: What does your code and sql looks like !?

Comment: pretty simple, just for test. ''use testdb; select * from testtb limit 5;" in which testdb, testtb are database name and table name respectively. And there are in different lines.